# Is there a method in Symfony that take a JWT (string) Token from HTTPRequest and decode It

Tags: symfony, jwt

I Am a new developper using Symfony, I try to work on a poroject using
JWT, for example I take a String "JWT" input from a post request, and
I need to decode It, and extract data from It, I tried to do :

```
{

     $post_data = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2NjE3NzUwMDAsImV4cCI6MTY2MTc3ODYwMCwicm9sZXMiOlsiUk9MRV9VU0VSIl0sInVzZXJuYW1lIjoibGVmb3J0LmF1Z3VzdGVAZ2ltZW5lei5mciJ9.btG_nhid4qmDa3xMkjybZb7v8T49e3SLoWHlML8yCXizdC0GY1dDr1sli8zwPJGfjaATxGmq4tMSCxAG7pXwSwtb_KMtg54cf8IZULEIBHhpkgiObXWwZ9BwQFc3_KCFOnXhKft6mIljROrDv0VKUxG7UhCCwfPaAA2goQNqpeYTP0Zo0s6QGZ2UZ03vUGnZuSoqmRwIQ_23_q6E9BW-1fVjDHCyGBzxgSObfkDB27f_DbJA-GWejTj_15d1ZFHcPF30O8QkNN0IS4pw4LhWa6LGUO0pWKVl96oOSQ0PV6F1KpjkCbTX6x3rdTY3p_btyFT5gxgzfF4lx2sMRWJtmeWvmKhO22IVsxcGpqEm-XF-NrWSA7BNLzVXgWA3H8E6f7ienSWiVoqxV8sGodHygn8as7mGaUmwgKJ-o3xQ6E99zFFFduatJYORV3mdmASbVbIcLqoGISBDQ1bSl_UkCppVrG_xpIlYyoTTINbi68VSqPZwfQHTcQy8ZZmvls_ipxzB7VSXSRmDJQIN4_rkn8N7UF1eVBP_Vhoy5qtnZACLuk6RHB4Hww_5Hfbb46vHtijfcPxplhRSqJqlki0zIeJk3YltCQ7I98cn6XCVfVKr-Tzmmb_cGKS8qv9R13PZQmSbwPbtHQGUltcbgafbAgypgkp53znfy_DiCS_sWxA";


    $this->tokenStorageInterface->setToken($post_data);
    $decodedJwtToken =
    $this->jwtManager->decode($this->tokenStorageInterface->getToken());
    return $this->render('jwt/index.html.twig', [
        'decodedJwtToken' => $decodedJwtToken,
    ]);
```

}

Any Idea Please?

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

I Tried This And It Worked For Me:

```
$post_data = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2NjE3NzUwMDAsImV4cCI6MTY2MTc3ODYwMCwicm9sZXMiOlsiUk9MRV9VU0VSIl0sInVzZXJuYW1lIjoibGVmb3J0LmF1Z3VzdGVAZ2ltZW5lei5mciJ9.btG_nhid4qmDa3xMkjybZb7v8T49e3SLoWHlML8yCXizdC0GY1dDr1sli8zwPJGfjaATxGmq4tMSCxAG7pXwSwtb_KMtg54cf8IZULEIBHhpkgiObXWwZ9BwQFc3_KCFOnXhKft6mIljROrDv0VKUxG7UhCCwfPaAA2goQNqpeYTP0Zo0s6QGZ2UZ03vUGnZuSoqmRwIQ_23_q6E9BW-1fVjDHCyGBzxgSObfkDB27f_DbJA-GWejTj_15d1ZFHcPF30O8QkNN0IS4pw4LhWa6LGUO0pWKVl96oOSQ0PV6F1KpjkCbTX6x3rdTY3p_btyFT5gxgzfF4lx2sMRWJtmeWvmKhO22IVsxcGpqEm-XF-NrWSA7BNLzVXgWA3H8E6f7ienSWiVoqxV8sGodHygn8as7mGaUmwgKJ-o3xQ6E99zFFFduatJYORV3mdmASbVbIcLqoGISBDQ1bSl_UkCppVrG_xpIlYyoTTINbi68VSqPZwfQHTcQy8ZZmvls_ipxzB7VSXSRmDJQIN4_rkn8N7UF1eVBP_Vhoy5qtnZACLuk6RHB4Hww_5Hfbb46vHtijfcPxplhRSqJqlki0zIeJk3YltCQ7I98cn6XCVfVKr-Tzmmb_cGKS8qv9R13PZQmSbwPbtHQGUltcbgafbAgypgkp53znfy_DiCS_sWxA";
    $tokenParts = explode(".", $post_data);  $tokenHeader = base64_decode($tokenParts[0]);
    $tokenPayload = base64_decode($tokenParts[1]);
    $jwtHeader = json_decode($tokenHeader);
    $jwtPayload = json_decode($tokenPayload);
    dump($jwtPayload);
    die();
```

And The Result Is This :

[image: Result]

Now Am Trying To Get The Password From The Decoded JWT

Comment: You probably want to take a look at some of the jwt libraries out there.  As you discovered, extracting the payload is easy enough but the real power of a token is the ability to detect if a mischievous client has changed the payload perhaps giving a user more roles than they really have.